# Show that the infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 + f_n(x))$ is convergent for $\mu$-a.e. $x$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space, and let $f_1,f_2,...$ be a sequence of complex-valued functions in $L^1(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ such that
$$||f_n||_{L^1(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)} \leq 2^{-n}$$

and

$$||f_n||_{L^\infty}(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu) \leq \frac12$$

for all $n = 1, 2,...$ Show that the infinite product $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 + f_n(x))$$

is convergent for $\mu$-a.e. $x$, and that the product is a measurable function.

I believe we want to show that $\displaystyle\int_X \left|\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 + f_n(x))\right| \mathrm{d}\mu < \infty$. In particular, we know that
$$\displaystyle\int_X \left|\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 + f_n(x))\right| \mathrm{d}\mu = \int_X \prod_{n=1}^\infty |1 + f_n(x)|\mathrm{d}\mu\leq  \int_X \prod_{n=1}^\infty e^{|f_n(x)|}\mathrm{d}\mu$$

where we used $|1+z| \leq e^{|z|}$. From here it feels like we should use the first condition since

$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty e^{2^{-n}} < \infty$$

however, I'm not sure how to combine these ideas together. For the part where I wan to show that thisi function is measureable I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: A product $\prod(1+a_n)$ converges absolutely iff $\sum_n|a_n||<\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $$\int_X \Big( \sum_{n \ge 1} |f_n|\Big) d\mu = \sum_{n \ge 1} \int_X |f_n| d\mu = \sum_{n \ge 1} 2^{-n} = 1,$$
the sum $\sum_n |f_n|$ is finite $\mu$-almost everywhere, and the sum $\sum_n \big |\ln(1+|f_n|)\big|$ also. Hence, the series $\sum_n \ln(1+|f_n|)$ converges $\mu$ almost everywhere, and its sum defines a measurable function.